# How to run puppeteer file on button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a index.js file in which i have my puppeteer script. And in order to run this file i have to go to the terminal and execute **node index.js**. The thing is I want this file to run whenever a user presses a button on the HTML.

So when the user presses the button i need to execute on the terminal the **node index.js** . I have no idea of node but how can i do that?

`Basically what i want, is to Execute Node command on button click.`

Comment: You need to setup a web server, with a public endpoint which will run your script. Then you send a request to that endpoint when you click on the button. Have a look at Express.js to quickly set up a server

Comment: isnt there another way to run "node index.js" in the terminal by making the call from the javascript?